# Mysql optimization: Can someone expalain why one query is working faster than inner join

Tags: mysql

So there are two queries. Why first is running much faster than second? How can I optimize my inner join to be as fast as the first one ?

Total records more than 4 000 000

idTerminals is indexed

```
select (select name 
          from terminals 
          where terminals.idTerminals = AnalyzeProfitResults.idTerminals),
        currency, 
        count(*) 
from AnalyzeProfitResults
group by AnalyzeProfitResults.idTerminals,currency;


select name,
        currency, 
        count(*) 
from AnalyzeProfitResults
inner join terminals on terminals.idTerminals = AnalyzeProfitResults.idTerminals
group by AnalyzeProfitResults.idTerminals,currency;
```

the results are same:

```
name,currency,count(*)
"Buy or sell",EURUSD,235105
"Buy or sell",GBPUSD,14515
"Buy or sell",USDJPY,235298
"very strict",AUDJPY,234787
"very strict",AUDUSD,235298
"very strict",CHFJPY,235298
"very strict",EURJPY,235298
"very strict",EURUSD,235298
"very strict",GBPJPY,235298
"very strict",GBPUSD,235298
"very strict",NZDUSD,235298
"very strict",USDCHF,235298
"very strict",USDJPY,235298
",normal",AUDJPY,235298
",normal",AUDUSD,36391
",normal",EURUSD,234985
",normal",GBPJPY,117649
",normal",NZDUSD,198552
",normal",USDCHF,235298
",normal",USDJPY,235298
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose in the latter query, MySQL joins `AnalyzeProfitResults` and `terminals` which yields `size(AnalyzeProfitResults) * size(terminals)` rows for the `group by` operation. With 4 million rows in `AnalyzeProfitResults`, that's a lot of rows even if `terminals` contains just a handful of records. In the former case, MySQL performs the grouping on 4 million rows which yields the 20ish rows you gave as result, and only then performs a subquery for each of the 20 rows (which might even be rewritten to a join internally, that would be even faster).

**edit:**
Here's the first query with an explicit join:

```
select terminals.name, APR_aggregated.*
from terminals join (
    select APR.currency, count(*)
    from AnalyzeProfitResults as APR
    group by APR.idTerminals, APR.currency
) as APR_aggregated on terminals.idTerminals = APR_aggregated.idTerminals
```

Comment: (which might even be rewritten to a join internally, that would be even faster).?
How query should look to join it internally ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the first query? It's perfectly fine!

Comment: when you want to take only one field from another table it is fine but when you want to take multiple field than you get multiple joins instead of one, which is not optimal solution for the most of cases

Comment: If you want to select more than just the name column from the `terminals` table, then no, it will still be one join. Even if there was another table besides `terminals` from which you would want to select columns, I'm sure it would still be way faster than the second query.

Comment: however I am interested to find solution with joins. My very first question was "How can I optimize my inner join to be as fast as the first one ?"... there are many other usages so I really interested how to optimize it